# Disconnect a Terminal Server session… is it even possible?

Tags: remote-access

Disconnect a Terminal Server session… is it even possible?

I am trying to disconnect a remote terminal server session. I wonder if I even have the administrative privileges to do so. Using this description: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785968(v=ws.10).aspx I have gone to the Control Panel but I do not find the Terminal Services Manager. Is it named something else? When I type it in the start menu I find and run some soft of System Properties window. Can anyone offer a suggestion?

[image: cap]

Comment: Ok, gonna need some more detail. What server OS are you running? Is the Terminal Service service installed? How are you connecting (some remote support apps like Logmein disable this app.

Comment: The answers so far seem to be focused on logging off the remote session. Do you want to log off the session (gracefully terminate running processes in the session), disconnect the session (session remains and processes continue to run but the client disconnects from the session) or reset the session (ungracefully terminate the session)?

Answer (score 2):

You can [log off](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755252.aspx) a user using the task manager however, you need administrator access for that. The easiest way to do that is to open a `cmd` console as *Administrator* and then run `taskmgr`.

From there, in the "*User* tab, you will have the ability to log off users.

Comment: I'd agree.  Although, I'd say the easier way is...
Right click task bar > Task Manager > Users Tab > Right click user > Logoff

Comment: @BradBouchard You cannot log off other users unless the task manager is ran with no restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Check the list of sessions from a command line with:

```
quser
```

Then can log off a session with

```
rwinsta session#
```

An example of an administrator kicking themselves off in a command window:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>quser
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>administrator         rdp-tcp#0           2  Active          .  23/04/2014 7:35 PM

C:\Users\Administrator>rwinsta 2
```

Both will take a `/Server:MyWinServer` parameter to perform the action on another server. This can be useful if you need to kick somebody off one of the two administrative remote desktop sessions so you can connect yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Spack's answer works well if someone is remotely connected into the machine that you are currently logged into as well, but it doesn't work on remote machines.

The new name for "Terminal Services" is "Remote Desktop Services", as it looks like you're using a recent OS from your screenshot. To get the new version of the console on a server, you have to be on a Server 2008 R2 machine, and have the Remote Desktop Services role installed. You can then find it in the Server Manager, add it to an MMC, or search for tsadmin.msc

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753397.aspx

Here are directions on getting Remote Server Administration Tools for more recent operating systems, and how to make sure you have the Remote Desktop Services Tools enabled:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2202.remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-client-and-windows-server-dsforum2wiki.aspx

To use the tool, you connect to the remote computer you want to manage, select the "Users" tab in the main pane, and select the user you wish to log off.